# Spring Framework: catalina.start.osgi

Tags: java, spring, maven, osgi, catalina

I'm going through this tutorial to learn a little about OSGI in practice https://sites.google.com/site/springosgi/ch01.html

I'm stuck on 1.3, when I go to "Apply > Run" I get build failed

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.741s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 22 23:16:54 EST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/54M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spring-osgi-tp: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-tp:pom:1.1.3: Could not find artifact org.springframework.osgi:catalina.start.osgi:jar:SNAPSHOT-1.0 in eclipse-repository (http://repo1.maven.org/eclipse/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

When it's downloading I get this warning

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.osgi:catalina.start.osgi:jar:SNAPSHOT-1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

I have done some searching and I found one thread that seems to be saying that the artefact is in the following repo

```
    <repository>
        <id>i21-s3-osgi-repo</id>
        <name>i21 osgi artifacts repo</name>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/osgi</url>
    </repository>
```

If I comment out the offending dependancy then it builds correctly though I imagine as I get further in the tutorial I will need this package to start Tomcat, is anyone able to give me some pointers in this space as I'm relatively new to Spring and OSGi?

Comment: Hi,Are you find a solution about this?

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** comment out the offending dependency. Instead add the `repository` specified above to your `settings.xml` so that this will also be referred to when downloading dependencies.

Also, not sure if they are copy/paste errors but these lines look suspicious.

> ... repository (http://repo1.maven.org/eclipse/) -> [Help 1]

This is an invalid repository

> ... start.osgi:jar:SNAPSHOT-1.0 is missing

The version number doesn't look right...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that this repository is already included in the pom.xml file and it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I have no idea of how I can verify if the repo is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>catalina.start.osgi</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>catalina.start.osgi</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Find in SpringDM tutorial download with dependencies
in the folder lib

copy file catalina.start.osgi.x.x.x.jar
to you maven repository\org\springframework\catalina.start.osgi\1.0.0

Comment: There are no catalina.start.osgi apth under repo. Also 1.0.0 does not work

Answer (score 0):

Same issue; 
I downloaded the [catalina.start.osgi_1.0.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcatalinastartosgi100jar.htm)  and take it from local repo.